# How do I format two different forms in the same stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, forms

Looks simple but I'm losing my head.

I want to format two different forms independently. Here is the example.

```
<h1>FORM 1</h1>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
<br>
<h1>FORM 2</h1>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

```
/* Form 1 style */
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
select{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

/* Form 2 style? */

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
select{
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dtpoze0c/

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the class or id CSS selector, so add an id like you did on the second to the first one: `<form id="form1">`

And then use it to create your style:

```
/* This will only affect the form with the form1 id */
#form1 input[type="text"],
#form1 input[type="password"],
#form1 input[type="email"],
#form1 select {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

You can see some doc about id here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Form 1 style */
.form1 input[type="text"],
.form1 input[type="password"],
.form1 input[type="email"],
.form1 select{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

/* Form 2 style? */

.form2 input[type="text"],
.form2 input[type="password"],
.form2 input[type="email"],
.form2 select{
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>FORM 1</h1>
<form class="form1">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
<br>
<h1>FORM 2</h1>
<form class="form2" id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```